# getting run time exception invalid column data2?

Tags: android, contacts, runtimeexception, illegalargumentexception

I am trying to get the contacts name and their types but getting this exception at line marked in the code.I was getting the names prior to adding the types,but now getting this exception.please help.thanks in advance.

```
 package application.test;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.Contacts;
import android.util.Log;

public class TestActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        String[] projection = new String[] { ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
                ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,Phone.TYPE};     

        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        ContentResolver ncr=getContentResolver();

        Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, projection,null, null, Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");
        Cursor ncur=ncr.query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null,Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");
        Cursor icur = cr.query(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, projection,null, null, Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");

        if (cur.getCount() >0 && ncur.getCount()>0) 
        {
        while (cur.moveToNext()&& ncur.moveToNext()) 
        {

    String id = icur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
    String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
    String type=ncur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(Phone.TYPE))  ;

    if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) 
    {


Cursor pCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, 
              ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?",new String[]{id}, null);

Cursor typecur = ncr.query( ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[]{id}, null);             


while (pCur.moveToNext()&& typecur.moveToNext())
{

                Log.d("names",name);
                Log.d("types",type);
              pCur.close();
} 
}
}
}
}
}
```

Comment: If my answer has helped you. kindly accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In projection, Phone.Type is not a part of Contacts Table which you are querying. 
Explain in detail, what you are trying.

If you are looking at Type of Phone, then you should be querying Data table

NOTE: I presume that you are using Android version 2.0 + and not 1.5 or 1.6

Comment: I am trying to retrieve names stored in contacts and their respective types i.e(home,work,mobile)..

Comment: Names are available in Contacts table, Type info is available only in Data table. You need to query 3 different table to get the info. 1. Contacts table, Raw Contacts Table and Data table

Comment: why raw contacts table..could you please explain this thing a little more.

Comment: Data table stores all kinds of info with Raw Contacts id. Raw contacts table stores, contact id

Comment: I tried querying different tables but same error at same line.... see the edited code.......

Comment: change projection for each table.

Comment: now getting cursor index out of bound exception index-1 requested with size of 10

Comment: I saw your other question you removed. 1st query for Raw contacts, then get the Phone type if available from Data table. Once you have this info, query for contacts table for display_name.